# Button that builds mailto url from CheckBoxes in a TemplateField, but opens empty in email client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I'm linking to emails like so:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmailList" DataFormatString="<a href='mailto:?bcc={0}'>&#9993;</a>" HeaderText="Email Members" HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" SortExpression="EmailList" />
```

I want to replace this with checkboxes and a button. Example:

[image]

Here's my controls:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  DataKeyNames="EmailList" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Button OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="&#9993;" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here's my codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "mailto:?bcc=";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            string val = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            url += val;
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Right now, this builds the string and opens Outlook. The location is perfect in my http requests, so the string is built correctly, but the new mail in Outlook is empty. No bcc.

I assume `Response.Redirect` is not what I want to be using. I also tried to `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` with a `parent.location` but that didn't work either. Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do can be achieved with jQuery alone since you are using `mailto` and not a server side mailing. This save a roundtrip to the server.

Start by giving the CheckBox an attribute with the email address as it's value.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" data-email='<%# Eval("EmailList") %>' />
```

This will render in HTML like this.

```
<span data-email="fake@false.com"><input id="mainContentPane_GridView1_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContentPane$GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox1" /></span>
```

Note that the attribute is in the surrounding span, not the input control. So know we know that we can create a javascript function that reads the attribute of the parent span of each checked checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function emailCheckBoxes() {
        var url;

        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                url += $(this).parent().attr('data-email') + ';';
            }
        });

        location.href = 'mailto:?bcc=' + url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer, but not what I was looking for. I updated my question with some changes to my code and my issue. Thanks though.

Comment: It looks like you are doing the same thing as me, but then with the c# code. First you never separate the bcc email adresses with a `;`, so it becomes 1 large bcc string. Second you are using a http redirect to trigger a mailto, this can give weird results, like firefox gives an `object moved` page after executing your code. But a part from that weird page it does open a new email with the bcc adresses (Outlook 2016)

Comment: I've got SQL separating the emails for me. It's definitely an issue with redirect and the mailto proxy.

Comment: Can I dynamically add client script that is self invoking, or that can be invoked once it's registered?

I found the method `GetCallbackEventReference` in `ClientScriptManager` that I'm trying to wrap my head around... Anybody know if that's relevant? It's sound like what I want, or I may just be an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I am just an idiot. All I had to do was change my default email from *Mail* to *Outlook*. It works fine with the application that 100% of my users will be using...

Anyways, here's where my code ended up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendMail(arg) {
        window.location.href = arg;
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="EmailList" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="&#9993;" runat="server" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string emailList = "";
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
      string val = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
      emailList += val;
    }
  }
  ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
  csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "SendMail", string.Format("SendMail(\"mailto:?bcc={0}\");", emailList), true);
}
```